# SVG won't scale

Tags: html, css, svg

Good Afternoon,

I know this question has been asked over and over but I can't seem to find the answer to fix my problem in any of the post i've searched.. which is a lot!

So I have a container Div which I want my SVG to scale to (100%).

I currently have HTML of

```
<div class="svg-lrg">
<object data="../images/sodium-sync-1.svg" width="416px" height="164px" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

I have also changed the HTML to try width="100%" as well as no width specified at all.

Div CSS is

```
.svg-lrg
{ width:100%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;}
```

SVG info (or at least what I think is the important bit)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 416 164">
```

I have the width and height set to 100% within the SVG.

It weirdly will be the correct size if changes are made to   on the google console but on initial load or refreshing the page it's too small!

I've tried clear all css styles putting it within a Div, incase something on the template is upsetting it

```
.clear
{all: unset;}
```

Still no joy...
Any ideas? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Why not use inline SVG like `<img src="../images/sodium-sync-1.svg" width="100%" />`? Do you want it to be cached?

Comment: Weirdly the image didn't show at all. Just displayed the icon for missing image yet clicking the link in the source provides the SVG image.

Comment: Just want to thank people that took the time to try and help. 
Turns out it was a problem with the way our test server was configured :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

HTML:

```
<div class="svg-lrg">
<object data="../images/sodium-sync-1.svg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

Setting both the `width` and `height` to `100%` will scale the image to the parent (`<div>`).

*PS.:* Your code wasn't working because you were trying to scale the `<div>`, not the `<object>`.

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried this too didn't work. It makes no sense. When I inspect the element and make any changes to size stuff it jumps to the correct size. So it's like it registers what it's supposed to do, but doesn't do it on first load?! :(